# Euler paths as colorings of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Given a connected graph $G(V,E)$, an Euler path (on edges) exists iff $G$ has either 0 or exactly 2 odd-degree vertices.

Suppose that $G(V,E)$ has $2n$ odd vertices. Let $P_m=\{G_1,\cdots,G_m\}$ be an edge partition of $G$ into $m$ connected subgraphs. Are there any qualitative bounds on the minimum $m$ needed such that each $G_i$ has an Euler path? Is there a formal name for this? Are there any quantitative results? My difficulty is in seeing whether you can even partition the graph into connected subgraphs with exactly 0 or 2 odd-degree nodes.

Equivalently, this problem can be thought of as: what is the minimum number of edge-colors $m$ that you need to cover all of $G$ such that each subgraph of colors has an euler circuit.

Here's an example on the famous Konigsberg Bridge problem, where there are two subgraphs (black and orange) on which Eulerian paths exist:

[image]

Comment: Does every $G_i$ needs to have Euler path in $G$'s vertices, or in $G_i$'s? 
If the first case is correct, then by having a graph with some vertex of degree $2$, there could not be Euler path in more then one set of the partition.
This could be generelize depending on the graph's minimal degree.
Also, the statement $G$ has $2n$ odd degree vertices is trivial in any graph.